# Pass String array to javascript from android

Tags: android

I have a question about pass String array to javascript in android.
I use this solution: `"javascript:showParams('"+items2+"')"`, but in javascript my array is only String. How can I pass array to javascript?

Comment: I don't think this is possible.  What I do recommend however is from Android serializing your array structure into a json string that you can then consume on your webpage.  I've utilized this technique in the past and it works great.